# Listing items in Azure DevOps associated with differences between two tags

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When we create pull requests we associate one or many items to the PR, sometimes we want to view items associated with merges from PRs between two tags - is this possible with the native DevOps functionality and if not is there an easy way to do this with the API?

Comment: Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also help others in the community. Feel free to contact me if you have any questions on this ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible with the native DevOps functionality?

I'm afraid DevOps does not have such a built-in function to meet your requirements directly.

> Is there an easy way to do this with the API?

According to the document of [list pull request work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), we only support checking linked work items based on pull request id but not tags.

We recommend that you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the feature on the [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).

As a workaround, you can manually view the pull requests and compare their differences.
Here is an extension names [Pull Request Manager Hub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caribeiro84.pull-request-manager-hub), it can display the tags and work items count of the pull requests. It may be useful for you.
[image]